# Meu app não roda no android Lollipop

Tags: android, webview, lollipop

Em um certo momento do meu app, ocorre o pagamento com o pagseguro, e para tal eu abro um página em um webview, responsável por esse serviço (passando os dados do cartão por GET). Quando a página termina de ser processada, o título dela muda com o status da operação, e assim eu consigo pegar para trabalhar no android (sim, é uma gambiarra).
O problema é que no celular do meu cliente não roda, android 5.1.1 . O pagamento fica processando até dar crash na aplicação.
Instalei a API 22, referente ao android 5.1, criei o emulador no android studio e deu tudo certo. Com a API 23 também funciona no emulador e no meu celular.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue módulo do webview

```
private void iniciaPagamentoCartao(String url, final Agenda agenda) { //1==cartao, 2==boleto
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialogPagamentoCartao == null) {
                progressDialogPagamentoCartao = ProgressDialog.show(act_principal.this,"Processando pagamento","Aguarde...",false,false);
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {


            public void onFinish() {
                String tituloPagina = webView.getTitle().toString();
                switch(tituloPagina)
                {
                    case "Erro contate o administrador":
                        progressDialogPagamentoCartao.dismiss();
                        progressDialogPagamentoCartao = null;

                        Toast.makeText(act_principal.this, "Erro interno. Contate o administrador!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    case "Erro no cartao de credito":
                        progressDialogPagamentoCartao.dismiss();
                        progressDialogPagamentoCartao = null;

                        Toast.makeText(act_principal.this, "Erro no cartão de crédito!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    default:
                        //faz as outras rotinas necessárias
                        String codigoTransacao[] = tituloPagina.split("~");
                        confirmaPagamento(1, agenda, codigoTransacao[1]);

                        progressDialogPagamentoCartao.dismiss();
                        progressDialogPagamentoCartao = null;
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: Esse é o problema. Como é no celular do cliente, não dá pra debugar e ver o erro. A aplicação simplesmente dá crash e fecha. "O aplicativo parou de responder"

Comment: Não tem como você simular o problema?

Comment: Não, porque pra mim não dá erro nenhum, funciona normalmente, eu usando o emulador com a api 22 ou com a 23.

Comment: Já percebeu se houve alguma queda de internet no momento da transação? Você tem algum log de crash? Já ouviiu falar no Fabric ? Pois é, o Google acabou de comprar. Tenta adaptar o Fabric dentro do seu app, é muito legal e útil. É um versão melhorada do Analytics do Google, porém usa o crashlytics para controle.

Comment: Provavelmente não houve. Eu vi que tinha se juntado com o firebase, mas não pesquisei a fundo o mesmo. Vou dar uma olhada. Obrigado

Comment: Não é Firebase, é Fabric. Veja: http://fabric.io/blog/fabric-joins-google/

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/FabricJoinsGoogle17.html -- Fabric and Firebase Joining Forces

Comment: Sinceramente, acho bem difícil encontrar uma resposta, porque talvez não dê pra reproduzir considerando a quantidade de código. Ainda mais que tem também o webview, e talvez, digo talvez, para fazer a reprodução do erro a pessoa terá que fazer uma compra usando o pagseguro. hehe

Comment: O Firebase já era antes. Agora veio o Fabric. Mas enfim, minha dica é você implementar o Fabric, enviar novamente o app, ai o cliente fará o o mesmo fluxo de antes. Desta forma, enviará para o histórico de crashs dentro do painel adm do Fabri, onde você verá exatamente qual foi o erro.